# Create Directory and Navigate into Directory c++

Tags: c++, windows

I have successfully made a directory in AppData Folder, but i want to navigate into that folder using C++ How do i go about it.

My code looks like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    //printf("Hello world!\n");

    char *name = getenv("USERNAME");
    char info[1500];
    const int bufferSize = MAX_PATH;
    sprintf(info,"C:\\Users\\%s\\AppData\\Local\\BizMail", name);
    _mkdir(info);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "navigate"? Change the current directory? (You should ask SHGetKnownFolderPath() for the AppData path btw)

Comment: _chdir would do it.

Comment: @AlexK. do something like this cd \C:\\Users\\Shannaz\\AppData\\Local\\BizMail

Comment: This method is unreliable. Use [SHGetKnownFolderPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762188(v=vs.85).aspx) and `FOLDERID_LocalAppData`.

Comment: @Shannaz Can you explain why do you need to navigate.. not clear from your code

Comment: @RushikeshDeshpande, i want to see the contents in the Directory.

Comment: @Shannaz You can always use functions to find contents in directory until unless you actually want your process to be running in that particular path .. take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612097/how-can-i-get-the-list-of-files-in-a-directory-using-c-or-c

Comment: @RushikeshDeshpande now i want to Execute an image from the same directory, did i get it somewhat correctly?

Comment: Better use  char folder_path[MAX_PATH];
 ::SHGetFolderPathA(nullptr, CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA, nullptr, 0, folder_path); to retrieve the folder path of local app data.

Answer (score 1):

Use chdir() function it works on both POSIX and Windows.
[Here is the man page](https://linux.die.net/man/2/chdir)

You can also use SetCurrentDirectory() function. [Refer here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365530(v=vs.85).aspx) and here is the [sample program](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363806(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: i made a few Edits now have a look at the program now

Comment: @Shannaz: Please don't rewrite the entire question after it's been answered. This was a valid answer, but it stopped making sense after you changed the question. If you're go a new problem, check if we already have an answer to your problem (we've got literally thousands of C++ answers already).